# get_role() method in discord.py asking for different arguments than in docs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to program a bot and am trying to use the discord.py docs. I need to retrieve a role by it's ID, which seems simple enough according to the docs here:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Guild.get_role

However, when I try and use this method in my code, it asks for the server ID as well. When both are put in, an error is produced. I have inputted them as both strings and integers and no combination works. Am I being stupid or is something wrong? This is my code:

```
    role1 = discord.Guild.get_role(123456789, 987654321)
```

and this is the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\---\main.py", line 13, in on_ready
    role1 = discord.Guild.get_role(123456789, 987654321)
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 560, in get_role   
    return self._roles.get(role_id)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_roles'
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your guild, and not use `discord.Guild` itself.

So something like this works:

```
guild = bot.get_guild(123456789)
role = guild.get_role(123456789)
```

Shortened version:

```
role = bot.get_guild(123456789).get_role(123456789)
```

Or if you're using this in a command, this works too:

```
role = ctx.guild.get_role(123456789)
```